# How do I get all combinations of a list's elements, according to a specific element(s)?

Tags: python, list, combinations

I'm currently trying to get all combinations of a list's elements according to a specific element(s).

I've attempted at using the `itertools.combination` method, but it simply gives me all combinations of the list's elements.

```
l = ['it', 'them', 'BMW', 'car']

c = list(itertools.combinations(l, 2))

# Output
[('it', 'them'), ('it', 'BMW'), ('it', 'car'), ('them', 'BMW'), ('them', 'car'), 
('BMW', 'car')]
```

To be more specific, I want all combinations of **elements that are pronouns with other elements that are not pronouns (i.e. specific selected elements)**. So the desired output would be as follows:

```
[('it', 'BMW'), ('it', 'car'), ('them', 'BMW'), ('them', 'car')]
```

Does anybody know how I might be able to do this? Thank you.

**Edit**

To be more specific, I guess you could say that I'm curious whether or not `itertools.combination` has a mechanism for which you could select specific elements and produce combinations with them.

Comment: There is no function in python that finds which items in a list are pronouns. But, you can split the list into two lists: pronouns and non-pronouns, then do a cartesian product of the two lists.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip. I'm aware that there's not a function or method that works specifically for pronouns, but I was wondering if the `itertools` library contained a mechanism for which you could select which elements you wanted. I hadn't thought about creating two separate lists though, thank you for the idea!

Comment: this is more like NLP

Comment: @WeNYoBen I was actually conflicted on whether to post this here or on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) but decided to post here because it seemed to be more focused on the Python code itself. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
In [1]: a = ['it', 'them']

In [2]: b = ['bmw', 'car']

In [3]: from itertools import product

In [4]: list(product(a, b))
Out[4]: [('it', 'bmw'), ('it', 'car'), ('them', 'bmw'), ('them', 'car')]
```